# Apply modifier to more than one element of an object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a document structure like this:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  name: ...,
  keywords: {
    group_a: [1, 2, 5],
    group_b: [4, 7, 6]
  }
}
```

I know I can add elements to *one* of the elements of the `keywords` object like this:

```
db.coll.update({_id: ...}, {
  $addToSet: {
    'keywords.group_a': {
      $each: [9, 12, 17]
    }
  }
})
```

Is there a command I can run to add the same set of elements to `group_a` *and* `group_b`? Something like

```
db.coll.update({_id: ...}, {
  $addToSet: {
    ['keywords.group_a', 'keywords.group_b']: {
      $each: [9, 12, 17]
    }
  }
})
```

which of course isn't valid.

I know the names of the groups in advance, but an "add them to *all* elements" solution is equally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can affect multiple fields with a single `$addToSet` operator like so:

```
db.coll.update({_id: ...}, {
  $addToSet: {
    'keywords.group_a': {
      $each: [9, 12, 17]
    },
    'keywords.group_b': {
      $each: [9, 12, 17]
    }
  }
})
```

To keep it DRY you can, of course, do:

```
var each = { $each: [9, 12, 17] };
db.coll.update({_id: ...}, {
  $addToSet: {
    'keywords.group_a': each,
    'keywords.group_b': each
    }
  }
})
```